# Paypal Chained Payment - Pay Key & IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I recently converted from basic Paypal payments to Chained Payments...and I have a few questions if you guys would be so kind to help out.

First, when I setup a PayRequest, I also create an order record in the database. Previously with my basic Paypal implementation, I passed that OrderId in the custom field as part of the form post to Paypal. I would then get that OrderId back in the IPN handler and use it to mark the order as paid or whatever based on the response from Paypal IPN.

Now I am wondering what is a good unique value for my locally created order? Should I use the paykey to look up the order on the IPN callback? Or should I just set the trackingId property of the PayRequest to be the order id and pick up in the IPN callback Request object?

Secondly, there is a returnUrl and ipnNotificationUrl for the PayRequest. Should the returnUrl process the IPN callback or does the ipnNotificationUrl only should do that?

The reason why I ask is because the return url must be able to show the buyer the status of their payment and the transaction info, the same data that I get in the IPN callback.

Thanks for the input guys, once I get these two minor details ironed out, I'll be good to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add your record ID into the tracking ID parameter of the Pay request like you mentioned.  That way you'll get it back in your IPN similar to what you're doing with the custom parameter now.

The IPN notification URL is what you want to set in order to trigger IPNs for the Pay request.  You do not want to use the same URL for return because then the script would actually run twice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I stick with using the trackingId to store my orderId value. 

In regards to the return url vs the IPN page...do I assume that when that return url loads after the payment is complete with Paypal, that the payment was successful and valid?

I need to display paypal transaction info on that page to the user including their order info as well. 

Can I pass some param to that page such as the pay key or tracking id so I can have something to look up the order info that was processed by the IPN?